# Generalizing mapAndUnzip

Tags: haskell, functor

I'm looking for an easy way to write the function

```
mapAndUnzip :: (Functor f) => (a -> (b,c)) -> f a -> (f b, f c)
```

I'm not entirely convinced that `Functor` is a strong enough constraint, but I'll use it for concreteness. I want to be able to apply this function when `f` has type (to name a few) `[]`, `Data.Vector.Unboxed.Vector`, and my own wrapper types around `[a]` and `Vector a`. (Other possible types include `Array`, Repa vectors, etc.)

My key requirement is that I should *not* need a constraint like `(Unbox (b,c))`, only `(Unbox b,Unbox c)`. Subrequirement: compute the function only once for each input element.

I see a way to do this for `Vector` by building two mutable vectors as I map over the input, but I'm hoping there's a better way than making a new class and my own instances for different types. The list-specific way that [GHC.Util](http://www.haskell.org/platform/doc/2013.2.0.0/ghc-api/src/Util.html#mapAndUnzip) defines `mapAndUnzip` makes me think a generic solution might not be possible, but I figured I'd get a second opinion before hacking my own solution.

Comment: There is already an `instance (Unbox a, Unbox b) => Unbox (a,b)`; moreover the representation of vectors of pairs is already by a pair of vectors `data instance U.MVector s (a, b)  = U.MV_2 {-# UNPACK #-} !Int !(U.MVector s a) !(U.MVector s b)` so I don't think there's trouble with `U.unzip . U.map f`

Comment: @Arthur Unfortunately, my own data types wrapped around vectors have their own associated constraint which does not work automagically for pairs.

Comment: I see; it is a little puzzling that you don't state their definition.

Answer (score 1):

`Functor` is enough, you can do:

(EDIT: Compute g only once)

```
mapAndUnzip g fa = (fmap fst fbc, fmap snd fbc)
  where
    fbc = fmap g fa
```

Comment: Ah, but this computes `g fa` twice, does it not?

Comment: Okay, one more nitpick: this requires two traversals of the output Functor. Can we do it in one? (the GHC.Util `mapAndUnzip` for lists, for example, computes the resulting pair of output lists one element at a time.)

Comment: Actually, a bigger problem: this solution doesn't meet my "key requirement" from the question: it computes a Functor of pairs!

Comment: @Eric Oh, I did not understand that key requirement, since any actual `Functor` must support arbitrary types.

Comment: @Eric In that case, I don't think there's any standard class that will allow you to satisfy both your requirements of computing only once and not going via pairs.

Comment: In some sense, you don't need to 'compute a functor of pairs', you can do `\f x -> f x = (fmap (fst . f) x, fmap (snd . f) x)`. But due to laziness, this will work the same as above - evaluating everything once if the pair is lazy, or twice if it is strict.

Comment: @user2407038 That's essentially what I did in my first revision (not shown, I guess it was too quickly changed) of this post. With just `Functor`, you can satisfy *either* of @Eric's requirements, but not both at the same time.